# Error loading trained en_core_web_trf spacyV3 NER model

Tags: nlp, spacy

After loading pretrained spacy model for finetuning on custom data

```
spacy.require_gpu()
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf",exclude=['tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer'])
```

getting error while loading for validation

```
model=spacy.load(category_output_dir + "/%s" % itn,exclude=['tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer'])
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/**init**.py", line 47, in load
return util.load_model(name, disable=disable, exclude=exclude, config=config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/util.py", line 275, in load_model
return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/util.py", line 341, in load_model_from_path
return nlp.from_disk(model_path, exclude=exclude)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/language.py", line 1705, in from_disk
util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/util.py", line 1085, in from_disk
reader(path / key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/spacy/language.py", line 1700, in 
p, exclude=["vocab"]
File "spacy/pipeline/transition_parser.pyx", line 479, in spacy.pipeline.transition_parser.Parser.from_disk
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thinc/model.py", line 529, in from_bytes
return self.from_dict(msg)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thinc/model.py", line 552, in from_dict
node.set_dim(dim, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/thinc/model.py", line 188, in set_dim
raise ValueError(err)
ValueError: Attempt to change dimension 'nO' for model 'precomputable_affine' from 78 to 74

here is the code snippet

```
import random
from tqdm import tqdm
import spacy
import os
import copy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.training import Example
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding, decaying

spacy.require_gpu()
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf",exclude=['tagger', 'parser', 
'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer'])

ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')
for _, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
    for ent in annotations.get('entities'):
        ner.add_label(ent[2])

for itn in range(n_iter):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
    losses = {}

for batch in tqdm(minibatch(TRAIN_DATA,size=compounding(4., 64., 1.01))):
    
    for text, annots in batch:
         examples = []
         try:
              examples.append(Example.from_dict(nlp.make_doc(text), annots))
              losses=nlp.update(examples,sgd=optimizer,losses=losses)
            except:
                continue
if use_optimizer_averages:
     with nlp.use_params(optimizer.averages):
         os.mkdir(output_dir + "/%s" % itn)
         nlp.to_disk(output_dir + "/%s" % itn)
         model=spacy.load(output_dir + "/%s" % itn,exclude=['tagger', 'parser', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer'])
```

Train data format:
TRAIN_DATA = [["Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "FRIENDS")]}],["I like London.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC")]}]]

Comment: Hm, it looks like there's an incompatibility between the model currently in your  `model` variable and the one you're trying to load from disk. Can you provide a minimal executable script that replicates this error?

Comment: @SofieVL I have added code snippet to reproduce error,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you ran into a bug with release candidate `v3.0.0rc2` of spaCy 3. We're working on getting this fixed for the final 3.0 release, see here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/6460

Meanwhile, I'm afraid you won't be able to add additional labels to a transformer-based, pretrained NER model. What I would recommend though, is that you train a new NER component from scratch.

In spaCy 3, we recommend using the config system instead of writing your own training loop (https://nightly.spacy.io/usage/training#config). In a config file, you can source components from other pipelines like so:

```
[components.transformer]
source = "en_core_web_trf"
component = "transformer"
```

This allows you to reuse the transformer weights of your pretrained model, and create a new NER model on top of that (https://nightly.spacy.io/usage/embeddings-transformers):

```
[components.ner]
factory = "ner"

[nlp.pipeline.ner.model]
@architectures = "spacy.TransitionBasedParser.v1"
state_type = "ner"
extra_state_tokens = false
hidden_width = 128
maxout_pieces = 3
use_upper = false

[nlp.pipeline.ner.model.tok2vec]
@architectures = "spacy-transformers.TransformerListener.v1"
grad_factor = 1.0

[nlp.pipeline.ner.model.tok2vec.pooling]
@layers = "reduce_mean.v1"
```

You could even source the old NER component from the `en_core_web_trf` too, just name it differently, and you'll have two NER's running in your pipeline, each for a distinct set of labels.

Alternatively, you can also use a non-transformer-based model such as `en_core_web_lg`. Adding custom labels to such a pretrained model should work fine, as before.

Comment: Happy to report that this should be fixed from v3.0.0rc3 onwards!